# How good is hash function that is linear combination of values?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hash, hashcode

I was reading text about hashing , I found out that naive hash code of char string can be implemented as polynomial hash function

h(S0,S1,S2,...SN-1) = S0*A^N-1 + S1*A^N-2 + S2*A^N-3 ..... SN-1*A^0. Where Si is character at index i and A is some integer.

But cannot we straightaway sum as

h(S0,S1,S2,...SN-1) = S0*(N)+S1*(N-1)+S2*(N-2) ...... SN-1*1.

I see this function also as good since two values 2*S0+S1 != 2*S1+S0 (which are reverse) are not hashed to same values. But nowhere i find this type of hash function

Comment: For moderate string lengths, that doesn't even use all available bits.

Comment: I dont understand whether using all available bits is necessary for hash function as long as we can avoid colliision ? As table of size of all available bits be not possible if we don't use compression function ?

Comment: All hash functions have collisions. The way you analyze your hash function is to look at these collisions and decide if they occur with an acceptable distribution. There is no one-size-fits-all hash function that best for all data sets. Your analysis has looked at when your hash function doesn't collide. Now try to analyze when it does collide, and see what insights you draw from that.

Comment: If you're not using all bits, then you're not getting the full range of possible numbers. All hash functions will have collisions; there's no way around that. The idea is to generate as few collisions as possible, and that requires involving all the bits in your result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose we work with strings of 30 characters. That's not long, but it's not so short that problems with the hash should arise purely because the strings are too short.

The sum of the weights is 465 (1+2+...+30), with printable ASCII characters that makes the maximum hash 58590, attained by "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~". There are a lot more possible printable ASCII strings of 30 characters than that (95<sup>30</sup> ≈ 2E59), but they all hash into the range of 0 to 58590. Naturally you cannot actually *have* that many strings at the same time, but you could have a lot more than 58590, and that would guarantee collisions just based on counting (it is very likely to happen much sooner of course).

The maximum hash grows only slowly, you'd need strings of 34 million characters before the entire range of a 32bit integer is used.

The other way, multiplying by powers of A (this can be evaluated with Horner's scheme so no powers needs to be calculated explicitly, it still only costs an addition and a multiplication per character, though the naive way is not the fastest way to compute that hash), does not have this problem. The powers of A quickly get big (and start wrapping, which is fine as long as A is odd), so strings with 30 characters stand a good chance to cover the entire range of whatever integer type you're using.

Comment: Eventually in multiplying by powers of A , we may have to use the compression( eg .  MODULO some prime number ) function to hash to valid range of array after which it may itself be reduced to smaller range ? (eg [0,MOD-1] and generate collisions . One advantage that polynomial  function may have is that it covers entire range not bigger range ? But I cannot figure out if that is so ?

Comment: @user3529205 covering a bigger range is not really a disadvantage (assuming a reasonable combination of weights and divisor), trying to avoid that is a bigger problem: you'd have to choose weights specifically for every combination of string length and desired output range

Answer (score 2):

The problem with a linear hash function is that it's much easier to generate collisions.

Consider a string with 3 chars: S0, S1, S2.
The proposed hash code would be 3 * S0 + 2 * S1 + S2.

Every time we decrease char S2 by two (*e.g.* e --> c), and increase char S1 by one (*e.g.* m --> n), we obtain the same hash code.

Even only the fact that it is possible to describe an operation preserving hash so easily would be an alarm (because some algorithm might process the string exactly in that manner). As a more extreme case consider just summing the characters. In this situation all the anagrams of the original string would generate the same hash code (thus this hash would be useless in an application processing anagrams).

Comment: But is this argument not applicable for polynomial hash function , considering S0*a^2 + S1*a^1 + S2*a^0, if we decrease S2 by a*a and increase S1 by a ?

Comment: @user3529205 That is true, for such reasons it is best to not pick a very small value for _a_ (_e.g._ 2). Nevertheless, the linear alternative grows much slower, thus similar discussions arise not only for S1 and S2, but also for characters further away from each other (thus there are more collisions in the linear alternative -- this is the same idea as in harold's response, where he provided the more rigorous argument based on counting).